# Soap response expect another element(validation failed)

Tags: c#, xml, validation, wcf, soapui

When I'm trying to validate response from my service(WCF). it Failed. does anybody know whats going on? or how to solve it? It returns correct xml result.
I'm getting such error

line 5: Expected element 'SPSCertificate@http://myuri.com/' instead of 'SPSCertificate@urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:SPSCertificate:18' here in element Get_multiple_official_certificate_xmlResult@http://myuri.com/

Comment: I think the xml failed the schema check which means you did not return correct xml.  It is possible the schema is wrong and the xml is good, but cannot tell without seeing the xml.

Comment: Which way you use to call the service, how do you call the service? Why did you mean that it returns correct xml result, while getting an error? 
In my opinion, is there an error occurs during the invocation?

Comment: <s:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <Get_multiple_official_certificate_xmlResponse xmlns="http://myuri.com/">
         <Get_multiple_official_certificate_xmlResult>
            <SPSCertificate xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:SPSCertificate:18">
               <SPSExchangedDocument>
                  <Name xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:23">Продукция жив. происхождения (№2)</Nam